# Нужна помощь в написании метода при использовании java 8 stream lambda насколько это возможно

Tags: java-stream, java-8

Вот собственно сам метод, тут слишком много всего и поэтому я немогу его написать нормально на стримах. Помогите будьте добры.

```
public List findAll(String nameFilter) { 
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(nameFilter);

    final int PAGE_SIZE = 1000;
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    int page = 0;
    Slice<Contact> contactPage;
    do {
        contactPage = contactRepository.findAllBy(new PageRequest(page, PAGE_SIZE));
        for (Contact contact : contactPage) {
            if(!pattern.matcher(contact.getName()).matches()){
                contacts.add(contact);
            }
        }
        entityManager.clear();
        page++;
    } while (contactPage.hasNext());

    return contacts;
}
```

Comment: а зачем вам здесь стримы?

Comment: @JVic Ну добавление в коллекцию как бы происходит... Влюбом случае буду очень благодарен за любую помощь. Извиняюсь не тот метод выложил сгоряча

Comment: @JVic  Извиняюсь не тот метод выложил сгоряча

Comment: А метод вообще работает ? ` for (Contact contact : contactPage)` вот здесь разве не надо дергать `contactPage.getContent()` ?

Comment: @Damintsew Безусловно, все очень четко работает именно так как надо. По 1000 записей дергается и нужное записывается. getcontent() не надо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Честно говоря не сильно я могу помочь Вам, но вот что-то. Я еще подумаю:

```
public List findAll(String nameFilter) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(nameFilter);

    final int PAGE_SIZE = 1000;
    List<Contact> contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    int page = 0;
    Slice<Contact> contactPage;
    do {
        contactPage = contactRepository.findAllBy(new PageRequest(page, PAGE_SIZE));

        contacts.addAll(
                contactPage.getContent().stream()
                    .filter(contact -> !pattern.matcher(contact.getName()).matches())
                    .collect(Collectors.toList()));

        entityManager.clear();
        page++;
    } while (contactPage.hasNext());

    return contacts;
}
```

### Вариант №2

Это при условии, что `contactPage` имеет интерфейс `Iterable` и он может сам дернуть следующие страницы. Если мы говорим об этом [Slice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html), то он теоретически может. **НО** у нас пропала возможность дергать `entityManager.clear();`. 
Попробуйте прогнать этот метод. Если что, то исправим

```
public List findAll(String nameFilter) {

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(nameFilter);
    final int PAGE_SIZE = 1000;

    Slice<Contact> contactPage = contactRepository.findAllBy(new PageRequest(0, PAGE_SIZE));

    List<Contact> contacts = Stream.ofIterable(contactPage)
            //.flatMap(contactPage -> contactPage.getContent()) //не уверен, что заработает
            .flatMap(contactPage -> contactPage.getContent().stream()) //теоретически так заработает
            .filter((contact) -> !pattern.matcher(contact.getName()).matches())
            .collect(Collectors.toList()));

    return contacts;
}
```

Comment: к contactPage stream не применяется

Comment: Вы используете вот этот [Slice](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/domain/Slice.html) ?

Comment: все исправляется getcontent, он возвращает лист

Comment: вот поэтому я и спрашивал:)

Comment: та я уже понял) есть идеи как внешний цикл тоже преобразовать?

Comment: @alexsafsafsd а есть у `contactPage` метод `nextPageable()` ? Который вернет следующую страницу ?